# Publishing my web application files to a remote server wwwroot

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to publishing web application and I'm trying to publish my web application to a remote server. I can connect to that server using a Remote Desktop connection but I cannot publish my application to the server directly from VS2012. I am looking for ways to publish the web application manually over the server.

I have created a new website on IIS 7 on the remote server and created a directory for my website under wwwroot. I'm not sure about which files to copy from the application to be pasted in my wwwroot folder. I tried copying my whole project folder under VS2012/projects, but I received an access denied message for the "Packages" folder in my project.

Am I doing it in a wrong way?  should I publish the files in some other way using VS2012 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use below steps**

1. in VS2012 - Right click on your web site in solution Explorer
2. select "Publish Web Site" option.
3. one Popup Dialogue Box will appear.
4. Select Profile or give Profile Name.
5. Select Publish Method as "File System".
6. Set Path for publish folder.
7. Copy that folder and paste it on your Sever **wwwroot** folder.
8. Open **IIS** on your sever and create website.

** **Make sure .netFramework 4.5 should installed on your server.**

For Host website on IIS 7 - visit the link - [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS)

Comment: glad to help you :) `upvote` the answer will helps other to find-out the correct Solution.

Comment: don't you have to restart the application or the server when you publish?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some useful link

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx)

[and here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx)